# Regex to match directory path

Tags: regex

I have come up with a regex string to match a directory path string.

I was having issues where other directories that were a sub-string of the search query were matching. ie. the search string was "pool0/backuptest" and would match "pool0/backuptesttest"

I have come up with the lookforward regex query:

```
(pool0\/backuptest)(((?=\/)(\/\w*)))+|(pool0\/backuptest)$
```

**UPDATE** just found that this won't work on Linux bash CLI as it doesn't seem to support regex lookahead

This will match:

```
pool0/backuptest
pool0/backuptest/testchild1
pool0/backuptest/testchild3/testchild1_1
pool0/backuptest/testchild3/testchild1_1/testchild2_1
```

And will reject:

```
pool0/backuptesttest
```

Is there any cleaner way to do this?

[regex101 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwo2c.png)

Comment: pool0\/backuptest($|(\/\w+)+) is a bit shorter, but works the same

Answer (score -2, accepted):

How about this, simply either match the parent directory, or any sub-directory (asserting that the parent must be followed by a `/`):

```
pool0\/backuptest$|pool0\/backuptest\/.*
```

https://regex101.com/r/kJHw6y/1/

Comment: Works perfectly and is far simpler than my attempt.